# basin layer from r.water.outlet Tool has values but is not rendering anything

Tags: grass-gis, watershed

I'm trying to deliniate a watershed with QGIS and used this tutorial to do so https://geogeek.xyz/catchment-delineation-with-qgis.html

1) r.fill.dir to create depressionless DGM

2) use r.watershed with depressionless DGM to create Drainage direction and "Number of cells that drain through each cell" layers. Everything works well so far

3) use r.water.outlet. I used "Number of cells that drain through each cell" to get the exact cell for my pour Point. The coordinates of all layers are the same. I used Drainage direction as Input raster.

I get a layer called basin wich has values but it does not render anything. I also add a screenshot that hopefully shows what I did so far. 
[image]

Any ideas what I did wrong? Is the DGM to accurate. Is my DGM area with 16km² to large or to small?

Answer (score -1):

I tried it a couple of more times with different values for "Minimum size of exterior watershed basin" and "Maximum length of surface flow" and now it works fine. Thus, These seem to be important parameters.